# Huffman code: shortest and longest code for Fibonacci frequencies

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

What would be the length of the shortest code and the longest Huffman code for n characters with Fibonacci frequencies?

From what I understand - if we build a tree, it will look like a one branch with each node of length 1 hanging off,  from the root to the lowest leaf. When we create the first node out of n-2 numbers, this node's frequency will be F[n]-1, and F[n]>F[n]-1>F[n-1]. (F[n-1] being the least remaining and F[n] will be the second least remaining), which, by induction, would apply to all the frequencies.

The tree we create is clearly an unbalanced tree, which, i assume, is not good.

If this is the optimal way to create a tree, what would be the length of the longest  way to create it?  If it is not the optimal way, then what would be the length of the shortest way?

I am new to computer science and I would really appreciate a good explanation.

Comment: Here is an answer that might help you in any way :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883086/optimal-huffman-code-for-fibonacci-numbers/19893487#19893487

Comment: i had a look at this link before posting, but i can't say that it clarified the question for me enough.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest code would be length *1* and the longest would be length *n-1*.  There would be two symbols with length *n-1*, and there is one symbol for each length in *1..n-2*.

There is only one optimal tree, and that's it.  There is nothing bad about it being unbalanced.  In fact it *has* to be that way to use the least number of bits to codes those symbols with the those frequencies.

I have no idea what you mean by the "shortest" or "longest" way.